# Scrollable table in wikitext

Tags: wikitext

In my company we use an internal wiki and I need to add a table but the table is very large, more than 100 columns, therefore when you want to see all the datas you can scroll horizontally but it is all the page that scrolls.
Is there a way in wikitext to make scrollable the table only ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overflow property needs to be on the parent of the table or to a simple div that wrap the table.

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll">
{|
...
|}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply arbitrary CSS to a table. Something like

```
{| style="max-height: 1000px; overflow-y: scroll;"
...
|}
```

might do the trick.

Comment: it needs to be on the parent of the table and it was horizontal scroll not vertical but thanks anyway.